# monitor a log file with Get-Content -wait until the end of the day

Tags: powershell, logging, monitor

I have a script monitoring a log file with get-Content and it waits for new lines to be written so it can detect the change. The logger changes the name of the log file every day to make it System_$date.log.

I am trying to make my Get-Content to wait for new lines as well as break when the date changes then to re execute itself with the new date in the filename. Does anybody have an idea how this could be done?

Thanks

**Edit**

The script looks like this:

```
Get-Content System_201371.log -wait | where {$_ -match "some regex"} | 
foreach {   
   send_email($_)
}
```

The file name which is System_201371 changes everyday, it will be System_201372 and so on, Also this script runs as service, I need to it to break and re-execute itself with a new filename

Comment: Can you provide a little more info or code? Depending upon the date format it might well be possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use Jobs for this.  Read the file in some background job, and let the "foreground" script wait until the day has changed.  Once the day has changed, kill the old job and start a new one looking at the new file.

```
while($true)
{
    $now = Get-Date
    $fileName = 'System_{0}{1}{2}.log' -f $now.Year, $now.Month, $now.Day
    $fullPath = "some directory\$fileName"

    Write-Host "[$(Get-Date)] Starting job for file $fullPath"
    $latest = Start-Job -Arg $fullPath -ScriptBlock {
        param($file)

        # wait until the file exists, just in case
        while(-not (Test-Path $file)){ sleep -sec 10 }

        Get-Content $file -wait | where {$_ -match "some regex"} | 
          foreach { send_email($_) }
    }

    # wait until day changes, or whatever would cause new log file to be created
    while($now.Date -eq (Get-Date).Date){ sleep -Sec 10 }

    # kill the job and start over
    Write-Host "[$(Get-Date)] Stopping job for file $fullPath"
    $latest | Stop-Job
}
```

Comment: I am using my existing shell script which is different than this but the problem with my script is that the "Task Scheduler" does not restart it automatically everyday because it was "already running" from the day before. Could I setup your script and run it "on start-up"? would it pull the new log files every day automatically or do I need to deal with the same problem I currently have? Looking at your code it will be stuck on the Get-Content line?

Comment: The code above should run indefinitely, and automatically do the right thing as each new days starts.  The `Get-Content` piece is running in a background job, so the overall script won't get "stuck."  You should be able to set this as a "on startup" kind of thing.

Comment: Ah I see, well I found an option in "scheduler" which basically kills the existing process and start a new one. If that did not solve the problem Ill work with your version which is much neater anyway. Is this what makes it run as a background job "$latest = Start-Job -Arg $fullPath -ScriptBlock {" ??

Comment: Hi Latkin, I decided to go with your solution because What I had initially is giving me a lot of problems. One problem I can't figure out how to get passed is that it does not go inside the background process - $latest = Start-Job -Arg $fullPath -ScriptBlock { Write-Host "INSIDE BACKGROUND PROC" .... this line never gets printed and it gets stuck right there. Do you know why this could be happening, I checked the powershell version I have which is running on 2.0

Comment: Jobs run in the background, and don't print results to the current console.  If you want to access the results of a completed job, you need to use the `Receive-Job` cmdlet. Try `$latest | Wait-Job | Receive-Job`.  If you have further follow-up questions, it would probably be best to ask them as full SO questions instead of extending this comment thread, since that's not really what the comments are meant for. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This, should always monitor today's log and  detect date change:

```
do{
$CurrentDate = get-date -uformat %Y%j
$CurrentLog = ("C:\somepath\System_" + $CurrentDate + ".log")
Start-Job -name Tail -Arg $CurrentLog -Scriptblock{
    While (! (Test-Path $CurrentLog)){ sleep -sec 10 }
    write-host ("Monitoring " + $CurrentLog)
    Get-Content $CurrentLog -wait | where {$_ -match "some regex"} | 
    foreach { send_email($_) }
}
while ($CurrentDate -eq (get-date -uformat %Y%j)){ sleep -sec 10}

Stop-Job -name Tail
} while ($true)
```

Comment: Looks like my answer is pretty much the same as that suggested by @latkin - too slow on my part! One thing it doesn't do is start at the end of the file, e.g if you we're to restart this during the day, any regex matches already in the file would generate new (duplicate) email alerts. You could use -tail option if using powershell v3 I think (haven't tried v3 yet) or make clever use of receive-job (I need to play with this, could be useful!)

Comment: Seems as if param is missing also, $Currentlog is null inside the script block