# Powershell - Monitoring live log file Q2

Tags: powershell, logging, monitor

I had made an initial question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28005726/filter-string-from-live-updating-log-file-using-windows-powershell) Which was answered but as i move along in my task I'm running into another problem.

Summary: I have a log file that's being written to via a serial device. I'm wanting to monitor this log file for particular strings (events) and when they happen i want to write those strings to a separate file.

Executing this one off does what I'm looking for:

```
$p = @("AC/BATT_PWR","COMM-FAULT")
$fileName = "SRAS_$(Get-Date -format yyyy-MM-dd).log"
$fullPath = "C:\temp\SRAS\$fileName"
Get-Content $fullpath -tail 1 -Wait | Select-String -Pattern $p -SimpleMatch | Out-File -Filepath C:\temp\SRAS\sras_pages.log -Append
```

The problem is the logfile gets a datestamp, putty saves it as SRAS_yyyy-mm-dd.log. So when the clock passes midnight this will no longer be looking at the correct file.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17411269/monitor-a-log-file-with-get-content-wait-until-the-end-of-the-day?rq=1) post on SO which is exactly what I want to do, the OP claims it works for him. I modified it slightly for my purposes but it doesn't write events matching the desired strings to sras_pages.log

This is the 'modified' code:

```
while($true)
{
    $now = Get-Date
    $fileName = "SRAS_$(Get-Date -format yyyy-MM-dd).log"
    $fullPath = "C:\temp\SRAS\$fileName"
    $p = @("AC/BATT_PWR","COMM-FAULT")

    Write-Host "[$(Get-Date)] Starting job for file $fullPath"
    $latest = Start-Job -Arg $fullPath -ScriptBlock {
        param($file)

        # wait until the file exists, just in case
        while(-not (Test-Path $fullpath)){ sleep -sec 10 }

        Get-Content $file -Tail 1 -wait | Select-String -Pattern $p | 
          foreach { Out-File -Filepath "C:\temp\SRAS\sras_pages.log" -Append }
    }

    # wait until day changes, or whatever would cause new log file to be created
    while($now.Date -eq (Get-Date).Date){ sleep -Sec 10 }

    # kill the job and start over
    Write-Host "[$(Get-Date)] Stopping job for file $fullPath"
    $latest | Stop-Job
}
```

If I execute just the `Get-Content` segment of that code it does exactly what I'm looking for. I can't figure out what the issue is.

TIA for advice.

Comment: So after midnight you need your script to keep checking the previous log file until a new log file is created?

Comment: I need the script to monitor the current log file, not the previous day. When the date changes it has to start monitoring the new file which will be created after an event occurs on the serial port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a few suggested changes that should make it work:

1. $p does not exist within the job, add it as a parameter ($pattern in my example)
2. You are referring to $fullpath within your job (row 13), it should be $file.
3. Add parameter -SimpleMatch to select-string to search for literal strings instead of regular expressions. (This is not needed but will come in handy if you change search pattern)
4. Referring to $pattern instead of $p (see 1)
5. Skip the foreach on row 16.

Like this:

```
while($true)
{
    $now = Get-Date
    $fileName = "SRAS_$(Get-Date -format yyyy-MM-dd).log"
    $fullPath = "C:\temp\SRAS\$fileName"
    $p = @("AC/BATT_PWR","COMM-FAULT")

    Write-Host "[$(Get-Date)] Starting job for file $fullPath"
    $latest = Start-Job -Arg $fullPath, $p -ScriptBlock {
        param($file,$pattern)

        # wait until the file exists, just in case
        while(-not (Test-Path $file)){ sleep -sec 10 }

        Get-Content $file -Tail 1 -wait | Select-String -Pattern $pattern -SimpleMatch | 
          Out-File -Filepath "C:\temp\SRAS\sras_pages.log" -Append
    }

    # wait until day changes, or whatever would cause new log file to be created
    while($now.Date -eq (Get-Date).Date){ sleep -Sec 10 }

    # kill the job and start over
    Write-Host "[$(Get-Date)] Stopping job for file $fullPath"
    $latest | Stop-Job
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but unfortunately it still doesn't work. The outfile never gets written to.

Comment: I see, I took a closer look and updated my example. Hope this will work for you.

Comment: YOU ARE AWESOME! I would upvote if I could but don't have the reputation points required.

This worked like a charm, I didn't realize that variables outside the scriptblock had to be passed to parameters inside but makes total sense though.

Thanks again!